# Why does Content-Security-Policy force Chrome to load Javascript sequentially?

Tags: javascript, html, performance, google-chrome

I'm having a website, which loads considerably slower, when I'm adding

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'">
```

to the head of the index.html.

After debugging for a while I am realizing, that all javascript sources are loaded sequentially when this meta tag is present. When I remove this tag javascript is loaded in parallel, so the website is able to load much faster.

To reproduce this, I wrote this litte sample html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'">
  </head>

  <body>
    Hello World
    <script src="angular.js"></script>
    <script src="angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="angular-touch.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the network timeline WITH the "Content-Security-Policy" meta tag:

[image: timelineWithTag]

As one can see, resources are loaded sequentially.

Here is the network timeline, when I REMOVE the "Content-Security-Policy" tag.

[image: timelineWithoutTag]

As expected, Javascript ressources are loaded in parallel here and the page finished loading much faster even with small example.

Is there any explanation for this behaviour?
How can I have the best of both worlds: parallel loading of Javascript files while also having "Content-Security-Policy" activated?

The tests were all done with latest Chrome at the time being (50.0.2661.75 (64-bit)).
Neither Safari nor Firefox show the same odd behaviour, they both load javascripts parallel also with "Content-Security-Policy" activated.

Comment: This may help you ;) [An Introduction to Content Security Policy](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/) you can create a "withe list", but i'm not sure it helps...

Comment: Does your domain have cache headers enabled for your static assets like JS files?

Comment: I am not able to reproduce that, https://mobile.twitter.com/ uses the same CSP header *(not in a meta tag, but should be the same)*, and it seems to load resources in parallell just fine. You should test it in other browsers, and see if the issue is just in Chrome?

Comment: Have you tried using the "Content-Security-Policy" HTTP header as opposed to the meta tag? It may be that setting it in the meta tag (which is read as the content is streamed in the browser) may be affecting how the algorithm for verifying the policy is done?

Comment: @TeaCode cache-headers are available, but this test has been done without using caching. I want to improve the experience for first time users, where the browser hasn't cached anything yet.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan
My webspace right now unfortunately doesn't allow my to change the http headers, which is why I'm trying via the html header

Comment: @adaneo testing with Firefox + Safari I cannot reproduce the issue. They all load the Javascripts parallel, its only Chrome that loads them sequentially.

Answer (score 0):

This is not reproducible on a MAC using

```
Chrome 49.0.2623.110 (64-bit)
Chrome 50.0.2661.75 (64-bit)
```

Both browsers are serving those three files from localhost in a few milliseconds and in parallel with caching turned off.

I also tried this on a remote server ie not localhost and both slowed down but all files were loaded in parallel ie I could see no difference with and without CSP turned on or off.

I believe there was a Mozilla change to move use C++ for CSP but that was years ago and it wouldn't be affecting Chrome.

https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2014/09/10/faster-csp/

Comment: Thanks a lot for testing this. I am running my tests on Chrome 50.0.2661.75 (64-bit) on a MAC as well. I also tested on Chrome under Windows 10 and am still able to reproduce sequentially loading the script files.
Are you also using Chrome developer tools, to watch the loading behaviour?

Could you please open www.sonopad.com/krono as a test. There I'm hosting my own files of the test.
Maybe something in the way the server serves them, makes a difference?